# Julia - How to use Array comprehension with ternary operator to initialize a vector

Tags: vector, julia, conditional-operator

This is my desired behavior...

```
result = []
for element in iterable
    if(condition)
        push!(result, element)
    else 
        continue 
    end
end
```

But when using an array comprehension in Julia with a ternary operator, I'm not sure what the analogous "continue" would be aside from using nothing. Which results in undesired Vector{Union{Nothing, ...}}.

```
result = [(condition ? element : nothing) for element in iterable]
```

For example:

```
vec1 = []
for v in -1:1
    if(v==0)
        push!(vec1,v)   
    else 
        continue   
    end 
end
```

returns

```
julia> vec1 
1-element Vector{Any}:
0
```

Meanwhile

```
vec2 = [(v==0 ? v : nothing) for v in -1:1]
```

returns

```
julia> vec2 = [(v==0 ? v : nothing) for v in -1:1]        
3-element Vector{Union{Nothing, Int64}}:
nothing
0
nothing
```

instead of just a normal Vector{Int64}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use an [array comprehensions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#man-comprehensions), you can use the `if` keyword:

```
julia> [x for x in -2:2 if iseven(x)]
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 -2
  0
  2
```

If you don't need to use an array comprehension, you can use `filter`:

```
julia> filter(iseven, -2:2)
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 -2
  0
  2
```

It is not possible to use a construct like:
`result = [(condition ? element : <SOMETHING>) for element in iterable]`
because this will always preserve the length of the input iterable. It is equivalent to a map, but it seems you really want a filter.

Comment: Ah ok that's perfect (using the if after the for loop) That's what I was looking for. Thank you